# script to zip a file and change its ownership

Tags: shell-script

I have a script I am working on that reads off of a text file and will use the information stored in the text file to put each line entered in as an array. This array is a reference to files that are imported to a directory in another script. The problem is I built a function to zip the contents of the directory and change it's ownerships, but when I run the script it was zipping and attempting to change ownerships of the `pwd`. Here is my code below:

```
file=~/exporttool/zipFiles.txt
index=0
declare -a studyinstanceuids
while read line ; do
        studyinstanceuids[$index]="$line"
        index=$((index+1))
        echo $line
done < $file
for i in "${studyinstanceuids[@]}"
do
echo "$i" | ./cmd2;
done
echo "Exams are in!";

##Function with argument that will take prompt to change ownerships
echo "What is the name of the owner: "
read $owner

zipForOwner(){
        arg1=$1
        for i in "${studyinstanceuids[@]}"; do
                zip -r ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip .
                sudo chown $1:$1 ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip
                sudo mv ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip ~/home/"$1"
        done
}

zipForOwner $owner
exit;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The problem is with the `zip -r ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip .`

I need to change it to `zip -r ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@]}"/20140620_"${studyinstanceuids[@]}".zip ~/export/"${studyinstanceuids[@}"/`

The `.` at the end was causing the problem.

Comment: I cant yet, it says I can only do it after two days.

Comment: oh ok, well then :(